# Incrementing a StaticVector at an index

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to increment a static array `A` at location `i` by `x`. If it was a mutable array, I would just do `A[i] += x`. But since it's StaticArray, I need to create a new one. However, if I new the size of `A` then I would do something like

```
A = A + @SVector [0,0,x]
```

and have a branch for each `i`. But in this case, the `SVector` is a user input, so I only know in advance using type information. I would rather not make my core logic all be a generated function just to handle this, so I was hoping there was an easy solution, or maybe this requires an `@generated` helper function.

Note that this problem is equivalent to creating an `@SVector` that has value `x` at location `i` but is otherwise zero. If there's an easy way to do that, then my problem is solved as well.

Comment: Why not use the `setindex` method that comes with StaticArrays itself? `A = setindex(A, i, A[i]+x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to get all the necessary values for this problem available at compile time. What I've got now is:

```
@generated updateindex(s::SVector{L,T},j::Type{Val{I}},v) where {L,T,I} = 
  Expr(:call, :(SVector{L,T}), (ifelse(i==I, :(s[$i]+v), :(s[$i])) for i=1:L)...)
```

or just to set a coordinate:

```
@generated setindex(s::SVector{L,T},j::Type{Val{I}},v) where {L,T,I} = 
  Expr(:call, :(SVector{L,T}), (ifelse(i==I, :v, :(s[$i])) for i=1:L)...)
```

And this can be used as:

```
julia> Z = @SVector [1,1,1,1,1];

julia> updateindex(Z,Val{3},4)
5-element SVector{5,Int64}:
 1
 1
 5
 1
 1
```

And benchmarked as:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime updateindex($Z,Val{3},4);
  2.032 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The code is minimal:

```
julia> @code_native updateindex(Z,Val{3},4)
    .text
Filename: REPL[13]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 1
    vmovups (%rsi), %xmm0
    addq    16(%rsi), %rcx
    movq    24(%rsi), %rax
    movq    32(%rsi), %rdx
    vmovups %xmm0, (%rdi)
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rdi)
    movq    %rax, 24(%rdi)
    movq    %rdx, 32(%rdi)
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopl    (%rax)
```

Does this solve the conundrum?

BTW if there are ways to rewrite this into a more readable form, I will be happy to see in the comments (and will update answer accordingly).

**UPDATE**

Chris's comment correctly noted that a version with a non value type `j` can be made:

```
@generated setindex(s::SVector{L,T},j,v) where {L,T} =
  Expr(:call, :(SVector{L,T}), (:(ifelse($i==j, v, s[$i])) for i=1:L)...)
```

Demo and low-level code (it can be seen a bit of performance has to be paid for not knowing which index to update):

```
julia> setindex(Z,4,3)
5-element SVector{5,Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 3
 1

julia> @code_native setindex(Z,4,3)
    .text
Filename: REPL[15]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 1
    cmpq    $1, %rdx
    movq    (%rsi), %r8
    cmoveq  %rcx, %r8
    cmpq    $2, %rdx
    movq    8(%rsi), %r9
    cmoveq  %rcx, %r9
    cmpq    $3, %rdx
    movq    16(%rsi), %r10
    cmoveq  %rcx, %r10
    cmpq    $4, %rdx
    movq    24(%rsi), %rax
    cmoveq  %rcx, %rax
    cmpq    $5, %rdx
    cmovneq 32(%rsi), %rcx
    movq    %r8, (%rdi)
    movq    %r9, 8(%rdi)
    movq    %r10, 16(%rdi)
    movq    %rax, 24(%rdi)
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rdi)
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Comment: Cool. That looks right. Thanks. This probably should be PR'd to StaticArrays.jl since it's more involved than I thought it would be.

Comment: Wait, why is `j` a value type? Why can't it be runtime? This looks like it only works if you know what index you want to increment at compile time.

Comment: Right. Added another version which is less optimized but with an Int `j`. Said it was tricky.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas See the addition. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Well, the `increment_value` version, which I updated using what you showed from the generic `setindex`. `@generated function increment_value(A::SVector{L,T},x,k) where {L,T}
  Expr(:call, :(SVector{L,T}), (:(ifelse($i==k, A[$i]+x, A[$i])) for i=1:L)...)
end`. Yup, that works well. Of course it does more at runtime because the other one can evaluate the `ifelse` at compile time, but this is fast and allocation free. Perfect!

Comment: @miguel's has updated his answer with an even nicer non-generated function version.

Answer (score 5):

The naive approach using [array comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1) would be

`julia> k = 4
4`

`julia> @SVector [i == k? 1.0 : 0 for i in 1:5]
5-element SVector{10,Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 1.0
 0.0`

This a good first step you could take when reading the [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) "Quick Start" part of the README.

However, we care a lot in Julia about [type stability](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/) and generic code,
because:

1. type stability in functions lets the compiler optimize -> speed
2. the code can be reused and extended in powerful ways leveraging [multiple dispatch](https://giordano.github.io/blog/2017-11-03-rock-paper-scissors/).

so a more Julian way would be to use

`julia> function increment_value(A::SVector{L,T},x,k) where {L,T}
    _A = [i == k ? x : zero(x) for i in 1:L]
    A+_A
end`

`julia> A = @SVector [0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
5-element SVector{5,Int64}:
  0
  0
  0
  0
 10`

`julia> increment_value(A,5,2)
5-element SVector{5,Int64}:
  0
  5
  0
  0
 10`

**However**, our final answer should include a way to avoid that extra variable allocation, and exploit some [compiler pipelining](https://tpapp.github.io/post/branch_prediction/) with the handy `ifelse` function:

`julia> using StaticArrays, BenchmarkTools

`julia> function increment_value(A :: SVector{L,T}, x,k) where {T,L}
            SVector(ntuple(i->ifelse(i == k, A[i]+x, A[i]), Val{L}))
        end
increment_value (generic function with 1 method)`

`julia> a = @SVector [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5-element SVector{5,Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5`

`julia> @benchmark increment_value($a,$3,$5)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
memory estimate:  0 bytes
allocs estimate:  0`

`minimum time:     3.178 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      3.285 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.293 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     13.620 ns (0.00% GC)
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000`

Comment: If `increment_value` is defined as `@SVector [ifelse(i == k, A[i]+x, A[i]) for i in 1:length(A)]` it saves an allocation and a branch

Comment: @DanGetz Static vectors don't heap allocate. Also, is `length` computed at compile time?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas The allocation saved is the temporary in `increment_value` of the answer. And the length is computed at compile time (in fact unrolled inline in the example).

Comment: @DanGetz doesn't look like your version works on v0.6. It says A is not defined in the macro.

Comment: I realized that this answer has an allocation in it anyways, so this is still not answered.